# Minizinc: Trivial equality unsatisfiable

Tags: constraints, minizinc, gecode

I have the following minizinc model:

```
include "globals.mzn";
var 0..9: A_1_1;
var 0..9: A_2_1;
var 0..9: A_3_1;
constraint (A_3_1+A_2_1+A_1_1) = A_1_1;
solve satisfy;
```

The model should have the trivial solution 0=A_1_1=A_2_1=A_3_1. However, Gecode and other solvers report this as unsatisfiable.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in MiniZinc when it translates the model to FlatZinc format. The message given is from MiniZinc:

```
WARNING: model inconsistency detected
test66.mzn:6:
in binary '=' operator expression
```

The generated FlatZinc file contains just this:

```
constraint bool_eq(false,true);
solve  satisfy;
```

and that's why the FlatZinc solvers yield UNSATISFIABLE.

Interestingly, the following model works, using a temporary decision variable, `T`:

```
var 0..9: A_1_1;
var 0..9: A_2_1;
var 0..9: A_3_1;
var 0..9: T;

constraint
    T = A_3_1 + A_2_1 + A_1_1 /\
    T = A_1_1
; 
solve satisfy;
```

The model then yield all 10 solutions with `A_1_1` is assigned values from 0 to 9, `A_2_1` = `A_3_1` = 0, and `T` is assigned to same value as `A_1_1`.

However, if `T` is initialized with `A_1_1` then UNSAT is thrown again:

var 0..9: T = A_1_1;

Update: One can note that the following constraint works, i.e. `2 * A_1_1` at the right side:

```
constraint A_3_1 + A_2_1 + A_1_1 = 2 * A_1_1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have filed a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

Your constraint seems to be attempting to use assignment operator but the operation maynot be valid. You may try a = b+ c  but b+c=a may not be allowed. Alternately you can try to use equality == operator to define your constraint which should work. I don't have program installed to validate but hope it gives you bit more insight to the issue. I would not be surprised if there is bug too, I would be keen to know.